# One instance in resultset not loaded

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a Spring web application that uses Hibernate as persistence ORM.
At some point, the user is asked several questions (which are ordered in sections by relevance) in order to perform some action.

In my Repository, I load the User's questions by the HQL below:

```
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
hql.append("select question ")
   .append("from User as user ")
   .append("left join user.definition as definition ")
   .append("left join definition.sections as section ")
   .append("left join section.questions as question ")
   .append("where user.id = :user");

Query query = getQuery(hql.toString());
query.setParameter("user.id", userId);

return query.list();
```

This gives this very strange result:

```
questions = {java.util.ArrayList@4629} size = 18
[0] = {model.Question@6692}"model.Question@49134043"
[1] = {model.Question@6693}"model.Question@ee01430"
[2] = {model.Question@6694}"model.Question@194d62f1"
[3] = {model.Question@6695}"model.Question@279ac931"
[4] = {model.Question@6696}"model.Question@230ec447"
[5] = {model.Question@6697}"model.Question@1e78234c"
[6] = {model.Question@6698}"model.Question@61556234"
[7] = {model.Question@6699}"model.Question@2ca275d8"
[8] = {model.Question@6700}"model.Question@5de6cecc"
[9] = {model.Question_$$_javassist_12@6701}"model.Question@5c12e33d"
[10] = {model.Question@6702}"model.Question@5c04e904"
[11] = {model.Question@6703}"model.Question@25c2cbee"
[12] = {model.Question@6704}"model.Question@17da89a0"
[13] = {model.Question@6705}"model.Question@c81739c"
[15] = {model.Question@6706}"model.Question@6cd0d2e"
[16] = {model.Question@6707}"model.Question@1c4a7f"
[17] = {model.Question@6708}"model.Question@415ed7e7"
```

There' re 2 strange things to notice:
1) The `ArrayList` has a size of 18 but for some very strange reason the 14th element is missing??? 
2) Another weird thing is that the `Question` instance at the 9th position is not loaded!
It is the proxy that Hibernate uses for lazy loading. But all the other instances are fully loaded (like it should be like defined in the HQL).

I've never experienced this 2 weird things before, I checked the database on potential data-errors but everything seems fine...

All help is very appreciated!

Below a more detailed view of the 'uninitialized' object:

```
[9] = {model.Question_$$_javassist_12@6701}"Question@218f5a04"
handler = {org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@6739}
    interfaces = {java.lang.Class[1]@6745}
    constructed = true
    persistentClass = {java.lang.Class@2709}"class model.Question"
    getIdentifierMethod = null
    setIdentifierMethod = null
    overridesEquals = true
    componentIdType = null
    replacement = null
    entityName = {java.lang.String@6746}"model.Question"
    id = {java.lang.Long@6747}"31"
target = {model.Question@6748}"model.Question@218f5a04"
initialized = true
readOnly = false
unwrap = false
session =  {org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl@6749}
"SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=
[EntityKey[model.Question#31],        EntityKey[model.Question#20], 
EntityKey[Question#17], EntityKey[model...
readOnlyBeforeAttachedToSession = null
sessionFactoryUuid = null
specjLazyLoad = false
group = null
questionType = null
text = null
uuid = {java.util.UUID@6741}"54e505a3-68ef-44a3-bf5e-e801e3443d79"
id = null
version = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer the first point (14th element missing). Since your are using left outer joins in your query, it will return at least one row for each `definition` and `section`, even if they don't have any matching `question`. In this case, the database will return `null` for all fields in the result (since you are only selecting fields from `question`) and my guess is that Hibernate translates that to a null entry in the `ArrayList`.

So check in your database if you have some `definition` that doesn't have any `section`, or if you have some `section` without any `question`. This could explain the first point.

You can also try to replace the left outer joins by inner joins. This should get rid of the null entries. Is there any reason why you decided to use outer joins in your query?

As for the second point, I suspect that there is something different at the data level for this record that will cause Hibernate to only instantiate a proxy instead of the full object. It is very hard to tell what without seeing your entity definitions. Could it be that all fields other than the identifier are null, so Hibernate doesn't see a need to instantiate the full object?

Comment: Your suggestion was correct! My DB test-data contained a section without any questions in it. I use a left outer join because I never expect a definition or section to have zero associations (-> not null). Is it better to use an inner join for this? Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped me a lot!

Comment: In this specific case it seems better to use an inner join since you don't get anything useful from the outer joins.